# ProcessLogger, only collect errors

Tags: scala

I currently use Scala to script in my Linux environment. I use it as an ETL process in Hive. 
When using the ProcessLogger class, I can't only get the stderr. Not sure why?
Which is a problem since the stdout is enormous when you do a query in Hive. I almosts always run out of memory.

If I write the following code which is like it is specified in the Scaladoc or in some examples in StackOverflow, it works fine has long as my query returns a small amount of lines. I get the output and the errors.

```
val err = new StringBuilder
val out = new StringBuilder
val logger = ProcessLogger(out append _ , err append _ )
val res =  Seq("hive","-e","show tables in ab_testing") ! logger
```

In my case, I am only interested in the errors, I do not care about the output. It returns millions of lines and I run out of memory. After doing some digging in the documentations or blogs, it seems to say that if you do it that way. You should only receive the errors.

```
val err = new StringBuilder
val logger = ProcessLogger(err append _ )
val res =  Seq("hive","-e","select * from ab_testing.ab_searches") ! logger
```

What happens if indeed the query blows or throws an exception, the StringBuilder gets the err, which is perfect, but if the query is valid it stills sends the Output to the 
**StringBuilder err** which makes my script run out of memory.

I am not sure how to handle the **ProcessLogger** to only obtain the errors or if I should use a different pipe operator to the logger in order to exclude the output and only keep the errors.

I did dig in the Scala Api to try to understand how to do it, I am stil confused as how to read the API's sometimes. It is the first time coding in Scala Daily.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
val logger = ProcessLogger(_ => () , err append _ )
```

It discards anything from stdout, and appends stuff from stderr. Using a single parameter as you tried latter is described like this:

> Creates a scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger that sends all output,
>   standard and error, to the passed function.

Which means it would get everything: stdout and stderr together.

Comment: Just tried this morning, looks like it is working. I tried it with a query that returns millions of lines and it did not crash. So far so good, Thanks for your help.